# Is there a "movie credits scrolling" style plugin for a list of words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'd like to display a list of a hundred words or so on a webpage. I'd like them to scroll up slowly, like movie credits. I can do that easily enough myself, but the problem I have is that when the user uses their scroll wheel I'd like the list to move up faster (and then slow back down when they stop scrolling). Also, I need the list to start over uninterrupted when it ends.

And, to add an additional level of complexity, I'd love the words to start at the bottom of the page at size 14px go up in size so they hit, say, 26px when the get to the top of the page.

Anyone think of a good way to start implementing even the first bit of an infinitely scrolling, scroll wheel operated list?

Thanks!

**Update:**

So, here's some code which I've made:

```
<marquee scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="10" direction="up" height="100%">
<ul>
<li>Bread</li>
<li>Pasta</li>
<li>Pizza</li>
<ul>
</marquee>
```

This scrolls up, but obviously the problem is that it isn't affected by the scroll wheel. I also don't know if I can get it to change size as it appraoches the top. I highly doubt this is possible using  but there's some code, anyway. :)

Comment: you should post exactly where you are stuck on the code. this could also be many questions until you complete your code. That's just a tip, as i see that you are starting out on this community right now.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am new :) I'll get cracking with some code and try to add some more info.

Comment: I should say, I was just wondering if there was an obvious jQuery plugin or something I was missing, not for anyone to provide me with all the code. But, I'll try to do it myself now anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fun... for those with Safari (including Safari on Windows)...
[Star Wars - the real thing!!!](http://www.gesteves.com/experiments/starwars.html)

Comment: true, removed all of the stuff that included that link.

Answer (score 1):

here is one
http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ActionSlideJS](http://liri.github.io/ActionSlideJS/) library.